# Dynamically generate child-URLs for posts or custom posts

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting, page-template

How can I have a post (or custom post) with a definite URL:

```
www.test.com/category/post-name
```

and a child-URL referring to a specific section of that post

```
www.test.com/category/post-name/sub-url
```

without being obliged to create a specific post related to that child-URL?

I have a post with the URL

```
www.test.com/category/post-name
```

originated by file `content-product.php` and I want to have a child-URL like

```
www.test.com/category/post-name/details
```

originated by file `content-product-details.php`
that refers/recall only a section/portion of the post.

In few words is there a way to create the structure indicated? Or do I have to manually create for each post as many sub-post
as child-URL I want to have?

Comment: If *any* of the answers was helpful to you, then consider accepting one. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just completed something like this (with great help from folks on this site).

First, you need to add the rewrite endpoint to your functions:

```
function wpa_read_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'sub-url', EP_PERMALINK);
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa_read_endpoint' );
```

Make sure to then go to the permalinks section of admin and save to refresh permalink settings.

Then add some code to do some template switching dependent on query vars:

```
function wpa_read_template( $template = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( ! array_key_exists( 'sub-url', $wp_query->query_vars ) ) return $template;

    $template = locate_template( 'templateFile.php' );
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_read_template' );
```

A couple notes:

- Refer to add_rewrite_endpoint info for different 'places' (in this case 'EP_Permalink'), I was doing pages so it needed to change.  (http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)
- Any changes you make to the add_rewrite_endpoint code will need to be refreshed by going back to the permalinks section in  Admin.
- When adding the template filter (add_filter) make sure you note the correct template 'type', in this case, single_template.  Again I was using pages so it was page_template.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say what you need to look deeper into is the *Rewrite API* and *Endpoints*, for starters see:

- [Make WordPress: Rewrite endpoints API](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/)
- [Codex: Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)
- [Codex: Rewrite API/add rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Additionally use the the [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=) on here, because there are already similar Q&A's, which will definitely help you.

Last note, doing such things manually can be painfully time consuming, so I would opt for automating it, of course at the end it is probably an assessment between investing time/money now and the later benefits - here you just have to decide.